# What's the keyboard shortcut for filtering CSS Rules in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking around their shortcuts page but can't seem to find the shortcut to filter different CSS Rules.

Does anyone know how I can access it? In my experience sometimes these things don't get documented, and would be helpful if anyone can clarify.

[Shortcuts Link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#styles)

I want to be able to access this area here:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quite look at the source code and there doesn't appear to be a shortcut key combination for that. You can, of course, put in a [feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) for one to be implemented. However, we'd have to consider what shortcut would be appropriate to use.

There's an alternative shortcut in terms of tab indexes in the Elements panel. By default, when you go to Elements, the `body` element is expanded. If you have no links in the outer elements inside the body, you only have to press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key twice to get to the style filter. If you have links, then it may be a few more times. However, you can press the <kbd>left</kbd> keyboard shortcut once to collapse the body, then tab twice. This means for the use case of just coming into the Elements panel (i.e. you haven't already been playing around in it), using <kbd>left</kbd>><kbd>tab</kbd>><kbd>tab</kbd> could be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to confirm this and for providing your suggestion on pressing tab key twice. This is very helpful for me : )